# How to resolve the Exception from WebTestClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

How can I achieve the following with `WebTestClient`?

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

mvc.perform(req)
        .andExpect(status)
        .andReturn().getResolvedException();
```

This is quite not the same, how can I actually resolve the `Exception`?

```
@Autowired
private WebTestClient webTestClient;

webTestClient.post()
       .exchange()
       .returnResult(String.class)
       .getResponseBody();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the following works, I don't know if it's the correct way:

```
...
.expectBody()
.consumeWith(res -> {
    Exception ex = ((MvcResult) res.getMockServerResult()).getResolvedException();
    assertEquals(ex instanceof MyException.class);
    assertEquals("Hello Exception", ex.getMessage());
})
```

Note this only works when having the `spring-web` dependency on classpath. Having only `spring-webflux`, this would fail as `.getMockServerResult()` is always null then.